# Android - Spinner async download does not function correctly

Tags: java, android, download, spinner

Upon activation of any button in the spinner the progress dialog comes up but nothing happens.  I had this working perfectly with buttons but don't understand what is wrong here when transitioning to spinners.  Anyone spot the reason why the download doesn't start up correctly?

```
public class SpinnerActivity extends Activity {

public static final int DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS = 0;
private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

Spinner spDownloadFrom;
private ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> spinnerArrayAdapter;
String url[] = {"http://www.becker.cl/bases.pdf",
        "http://www.pitt.edu/documents/campusmap0607.pdf", "http://www.aara.ca/reg3317/web_page_doc.pdf",
        "www.dataprotection.ie/documents/guidance/GuidanceFinance.pdf", "http://www.fmbb2012.com/JumpingQualifica1.pdf",
        "http://www.consulatdumaroc.ca/coloniefh22012.pdf", "http://www.rgrdlaw.com/media/cases/140_Complaint.pdf" };
String name[] = { "bases.pdf", "campusmap0607.pdf", "web_page_doc.pdf", "GuidanceFinance.pdf",
        "JumpingQualifica1.pdf", "coloniefh22012.pdf", "140_Complaint.pdf", };

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(SpinnerActivity.this);
    mProgressDialog.setMessage("Please be patient, file downloading...");
    mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    mProgressDialog.setMax(100);
    mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);

    spDownloadFrom = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner01);

    spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, name);
    spinnerArrayAdapter
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spDownloadFrom.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

    spDownloadFrom.setOnItemSelectedListener(new SpinnerListener(
            spDownloadFrom));
}

public class SpinnerListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {
    Spinner sp;

    public SpinnerListener(View v) {
        sp = (Spinner) findViewById(v.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        // Call to download class
        startDownload(arg2);


    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}

private void startDownload(Integer... url) {
    DownloadFile downloadFile = new DownloadFile();
    downloadFile.execute();

}

class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> { // put your
                                                                // download
                                                                // code

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
        mProgressDialog.setProgress(progress[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {
        try {

            URL url = new URL(aurl[0]);
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

            connection.connect();
            int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();
            int tickSize = 2 * fileLength / 100;
            int nextProgress = tickSize;

            Log.d(

            "ANDRO_ASYNC", "Lenght of file: " + fileLength);

            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());

            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + "/Android/Data/"
                    + getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + "/files/" + name;
            File file = new File(path);
            file.mkdirs();
            File outputFile = file;

            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

            byte data[] = new byte[1024 * 1024];
            long total = 0;
            int count;
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                if (total >= nextProgress) {
                    nextProgress = (int) ((total / tickSize + 1) * tickSize);
                    this.publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / fileLength));
                }
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
        Log.d("Downloading", progress[0]);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {

        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + "/Android/Data/"
                + getApplicationContext().getPackageName()
                + "/files/" + name);
        Intent testIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        testIntent.setType("application/pdf");
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
        try {
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(SpinnerActivity.this,
                    "No Application Available to View PDF",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `startDownload` method, you are passing in `url`, which is an array of `String` type. In `doInBackground` of your `AsyncTask`, you are only using the first index of `url`, which you have set as `""`, so you're passing in an empty `String`.

To pass in the URL you are expecting, change the `startDownload` method to accept an `int` value. Then in the `onItemSelected` method, pass in the position, which you have named as `arg2` (The parameter names should be parent, view, position, and id, in that order. Easier to understand what they mean). Then when you call `downloadFile.execute`, pass in `url[position]`.

**Edit**

Change your download method to like this:

```
private void startDownload(int position) {
    DownloadFile downloadFile = new DownloadFile();
    downloadFile.execute(url[position]);
}
```

That should give you the expected results, assuming the URLs you are using are valid. Also, your dialog isn't going away because you forgot to call `mProgressDialog.dismiss()` in `onPostExecute`.

Comment: After changing to ItemClick instead of ItemSelected I get Force Close, updated with code and logcat of crash.

Comment: Ahh, that method isn't supported by `Spinner`. Sorry, I gave you a bad answer. Can you change it back to `onItemSelected` and print out a `Log` inside the listener? Let me know if that log ever gets printed to LogCat.

Comment: Changed back to original post.  Nothing gets printed to LogCat, but what happens is when the app comes up the progress dialog opens immediately and I get the toast message no PDF view available.

Comment: OK, I made some of the edits that you suggested, I think anyway.  I don't think I correctly handled the startDownload method or the onItemSelected method.  can you take a look at those and see what I did wrong? It is still doing the progress bar and toast message.

Comment: Awesome Thank you!  I still have a few issues but I'll ask a new question about it.  Thanks again. -if your up for it the question deals with the file not saving on the SD card at all, and the progress bar not populating - it stays at zero.